# How to get an executable for a Python script to be run using anaconda environment in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I don't want to convert my .py file to .exe file. Rather I want a simple .exe file which can activate my anaconda virtual environment and run the script kept at a particular directory path. Any idea how to do it!

Comment: What languages do you have available to you that you'd want to use to write the .exe? Also, why do you want to use a .exe instead of for example a .bat, or .ps1?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an Anaconda environment with name *saputara* with which you want to run *hello_world.py* kept at the directory *E:\vaibhav\work*. Copy following peace of code to the notepad

```
E:
cd vaibhav\work\
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
call activate saputara
python hello_world.py
pause
```

Now save this file with extension *.bat*. Double clicking on this file will automatically execute hello_world.py

Answer (score 0):

use the bat scripting to get your task done.

```
@echo off
conda activate env_name
python file_name.py
```

copy this to a notepad and save it as a .exe file. This will activate a conda environment there and run the python script.

### OR

```
@echo off
cd %1
conda activate env_name
python %2.py
```

run this using cmd cause it takes two parameters. first the directory path and second the file name
you can google if you wanna know more about bat scripting.
You can add it to path as well to use it from anywhere.

Comment: You can't just save a .bat script as an executable and expect it to work. The advice to use a .bat instead of writing a .exe isn't bad per se, but there may be reasons why OP requires an actual .exe to run their script.